# Вопрос про UITableView и UITableViewCell в iOS

Tags: ios, uitableview

Доброе время суток коллеги!

Столкнулся с такой задачей. Необходимо выводить информацию в UITableView в два кастомных UITableViewCell. верхний как бы заголовок, нижний текст с произвольной высотой. Если кликать на заголовок необходимо попадать на профиль пользователя, если кликать на текст попадать на полный текст статьи. Пример реализации которая мне нужна хорошо выполнен в приложении ВКонтакте для iphone, в разделе группы. У меня не получается вывести данные в два UITableViewCell по очереди.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/g1g6btk4zudrhr1/screen.pdf

В приложенном файле я нарисовал прототип того как должен выглядеть табличный вид на мобильном телефоне.

Если кто сталкивался или знает как это можно реализовать прощу помочь.

Comment: Если я верно Вас понял - Вам нужно использовать кастомные ячейки. Прикрепите UITapGesture к лейблам в которые выводите информацию или что еще проще - сделайте на невидимые кнопки на фоне текстовых блоков и по ним запускайте анимацию перехода на соответствующий экран.

Comment: Автор же и пишет, что ему необходимо выводить информацию в две кастомные ячейки!

Comment: @huffman, это точно, что у вас должно быть именно две разные ячейки - то есть не идут ли они у вас всегда парами? Если так, то почему бы вам не использовать одну ячейку, которая содержала бы в себе две ваших под-ячейки?

Comment: Ваша pdf-иллюстрация заставляет меня думать, что вас есть только один вид ячейки, просто ячейка составная и состоит из двух подсекций-"подячеек". Это так? Бывает, что ячейки одного типа, например, ячейки типа "многострочный текст", идут подряд, без автора в промежутку между ними?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

После обсуждения этого вопроса с его автором в скайпе мы совместно выяснили, что оба вида ячеек на самом деле относятся к одной сущности (пользователю и контенту, связанному с ним) и решили, что нужно, чтобы был создан только один тип ячейки, в которую контент нынешних двух типов ячейки войдет в виде двух subviews - один subview для заголовка ячейки (информация о пользователе), другой - для контента (сообщение пользователя).

Главная же проблема скрывалась в том, что из-за наличия двух видов ячеек, автор, полагаясь на строку вида

```
EXHeaderTableCell *headerCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:HeaderCellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
```

получал неправильное обращение к индексу в массиве Reusable cells, так как indexPath в большинстве случаев указывал на ячейку противоположного типа.

Comment: Станислав, спасибо за помощ в решении моего вопроса.

Answer (score 2):

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellPersonIdentifier = @"CellPersonIdentifier";
    static NSString *CellDataIdentifier = @"CellDataIdentifier";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:(indexPath.row % 2 == 0 ? CellPersonIdentifier : CellDataIdentifier)];

    if (cell == nil)
    {
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:(indexPath.row % 2 == 0 ? @"CellPerson" : @"CellData") owner:self options:nil];
        cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
    }
    // далее заполняешь ячейки данными
}
```

Comment: @ruman, чтобы не дублировать ваш ответ, я просто подскажу вам, что ваше решение с (indexPath.row % 2 == 0) достаточно грубое и сразу предполагает, что ячейки идут строго парами. Добавьте в ваш ответ проверку на тип данных, которые спрашиваются по соответствующему индексу и уже на основе типа данных уже определяйте класс кастомной ячейки. Я в таких случаях делаю typedef enum с перечислением возможных типов данных. Под "типом данных" я имею в виду один из двух возможных вариантов "контента" для двух видов ячеек.

Comment: Сейчас проверить не могу (написал код с коленки)), но по моему можно просто преобразование типа сделать:
    if (indexPath.row % 2 == 0)
        ((CustomPersonCell *)cell).personTitle ...
    else
        ((CustomDataCell *)cell).dataDescription ....

Согласен, грубо. Предпологается, что ячейки всегда идут парно.

Comment: В целом, все верно. Посмотрим, как уточнит свою задачу автор вопроса. Плюсую ваш ответ.

Comment: Я пытался сделать следующим образом. В раскадровке на экране с UITableView добавил два UITableViewCell с разными идентификаторами и расположил необходимые контролы.  Код примерно такой же как указаны в примере. Но в результате у меня получается, что все ячейки заполняются ячейкой которая расположена в раскодроке на UITableView в самом верху. Исходный текст привести не могу так как он не влез по кол-ву символов -(

Comment: снимок экрана с расположением UITableViewCell и контролов:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/91wh5p6s3z68ako/tableview.tiff

снимок экрана как это работает: https://www.dropbox.com/s/yw9ook50k5s64q3/tableview2.tiff

Comment: вот тут как это выглядит в работающем приложении https://www.dropbox.com/s/38dl50pqybq9icg/photo.PNG приложение Вконтакте для ios раздел группы. Заголовок и текст под заголовком кликабельные как отдельные UITableViewCell.